# Constructor in PHP

Tags: php, class, methods, constructor

Does a constructor method in PHP take the parameters declared in the class or not?

I've seen on multiple sites and books and in the PHP documentation that the function function __construct() doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: `__construct` can take params the same as any other method can.

Comment: You must be reading the wrong books and docs - constructors can take as many parameters as you define

Comment: When in doubt - just read up on stuff like this in the official documentation, instead of relying on 3rd-party resources. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Actually I wonder what you mean by "the parameters declared in the class"... A class has no declared parameters, only methods (functions) have. The constructor is such a method. It will take any parameters declared in its implementation.

Answer (score 21):

The PHP constructor can take parameters like the other functions can. It's not required to add parameters to the `__construct()` function, for example:

Example 1: Without parameters

```php
<?php
class example {
    public $var;
    function __construct() {
        $this->var = "My example.";
    }
}
$example = new example;
echo $example->var; // Prints: My example.
?>
```

Example 2: with parameters

```php
<?php
class example {
    public $var;
    function __construct($param) {
        $this->var = $param;
    }
}
$example = new example("Custom parameter");
echo $example->var; // Prints: Custom parameter
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

`__construct` can take parameters. According to [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), this method signature is:

```
void __construct ([ mixed $args = "" [, $... ]] )
```

So it seems it can take parameters!

How to use it:

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct($a) {
        echo $a;
    }
}

$a = new MyClass('Hello, World!'); // Will print "Hello, World!"
```